# Download from S3 with Foxpro - any recent examples?

Tags: amazon-s3, visual-foxpro, foxpro

I'm looking to download images from an S3 Bucket in a Foxpro application. I've downloaded the usually-infallible Chilkat bundle, but I'm either getting Access Denied with the old style S3_DownloadFile method (presumably to be expected because S3 doesn't accept http with no auth any more), or WSAECONNABORTED with the newer SendReqNoBody method, which may be firewall or anti-virus related but it all seems to be allowed.

Has anyone made this work recently?

Comment: It is documented here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_GetObject.html and also they suggest using AWS CLI.  I would use Microsoft.XMLHttp for API.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks! The problem actually lay in a bad filepath, and needing to connect & authenticate directly before requesting the download.